# what's the output of following code and why?

Tags: c

The following code is an interview qusetion and I can't understand the output. Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    char* string_1()
    {
       char* p = "ABCD";
       return p;
    }

    char* string_2()
    {
       char p[] = "ABCD";
       return p;
    }

    int main(void)
    {
       printf("%s\n",string_1());
       printf("%s\n",string_2());
    }
```

Comment: What is the output? What do you expect for the output?

Comment: The first one is ABCD as expected, the second one is Undefined Behaviour as you are returning a local variable which has gone out of scope.

Comment: @PaulR: Why not post your comment as answer?

Comment: @alk: sure - comment converted to answer (I thought this would have been closed as a duplicate by now).

Comment: @H2CO3,thanks for your help.Aha,,I'm not the interviewee,I'm just a rookie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is ABCD as expected, the second one is Undefined Behaviour as you are returning a local variable which has gone out of scope.

Comment: Note that the first one need not be ABCD. If a program invokes undefined behavior, that concerns the **entire** code, and there are absolutely no requirements at all, not even before control flow reaches the erroneous part.

Answer (score 2):

> what's the output

We don't know. Any output is valid...

> and why

... because the code invokes undefined behavior. In the second function, you are returning a pointer to the first element of a block-scoped array with automatic storage duration, which is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

First one gives ABCD as output because

```
  char* p = "ABCD";
```

In the above statement ABCD is string literal therefore it gets stored in read only memory.The starting adders gets assigned to p,which is returned to main .Hence ABCD gets printed.

Whereas here

```
 char p[] = "ABCD";
```

ABCD is not a string literal.It is assigned to the local variable.As we know the scope of the local variable is the function body.Here you are returning a local variable which leads to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Does this mean that the literal string is copied to local variable p when the second function is called (if we ignore non-generated code by optimization)?